# Difference between int p = *(int *)i and int p = *(int *)&i

Tags: c++, c, pointers, casting

The following question was asked in a recent microsoft interview.

What is the difference between the two declarations?

```
int p=*(int*)i; 
int p=*(int*)&i;
```

I think in the first one `i` is a pointer and in the second one `i` is a variable.
Is there anything else?

Comment: Any sufficiently advanced diff program will tell you it's an ampersand on the 14th column.

Comment: How is `i` declared? If it's an `int`, then `&i` is already of type `int*`, and the cast in the second line is superfluous.

Comment: it kind of depends on the type of i.

Comment: The question makes virtually no sense whatsoever without knowing what `i` is. As stated, it has only one answer: the one Martinho gave you in the comment above.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first is taking the value contained in `i`, treating it as a pointer, and retrieving whatever `int` value is at that address (if possible).

The second takes the address of `i`, casts it to pointer to int, and retrieves the value at that address. If `i` is an `int`, it's equivalent to `p=i;`. If it's not, it's going to take the first `CHAR_BIT *sizeof(int)` bits starting at the address of `i`, and (attempt to) treat them as an `int`, and assign whatever value that creates to `p`.

Edit: and yes, as @R. Martinho Fernandes pointed out, if `i` has an overloaded `operator &`, it may do something rather different from any of the above (i.e., instead of the address of `i` it'll start with whatever its `operator &` returns).

Comment: Unless the type of `i` is evil, i.e., has an overloaded `operator&`! :P

Comment: Formally, of course, if `i` isn't `int`, the second results in undefined behavior.  It could crash, if `i` has less strict alignment requirements than `int`, and it could crash if `i` was smaller than `int`, and just happened to be at the very end of mapped memory.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the language then this question boils down to what is the difference betweeen

```
i
```

and

```
&i
```

And the answer is that in the first case it's `i` and in the second case it's address of `i`, and then you have all those conversions to act on either of these two.